# Using Flutter webview controller in initstate

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

I am new to flutter, I am trying to add few javascript.evaluations functions using webview controller method

```
  body: WebView(
    key: key,
    initialUrl: url,
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
      _webViewController = controller;
    },
```

Works fine if I do it as,

```
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue[700],
        selectedFontSize: 13,
        unselectedFontSize: 13,
        iconSize: 30,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "Feed",
            icon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              **onPressed: () {
                _webViewController.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/");
              },**
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "Screen",
            icon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.grid_view),
              onPressed: () {
                **_webViewController
                    .loadUrl("https://www.google.com");**
              },
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "Tools",
            icon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              **onPressed: () {
                _webViewController.evaluateJavascript(
                    "Modal.showInModal('#nav-tools')");**
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
```

The problem here being the UI is messed up, icons appear small, too much space between icon and text.

So when tried using the bottom set index method, it doesn't seem to work

```
  final tabs = [
    _webViewController.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/"),
    _webViewController.loadUrl("https://www.google.com"),
    _webViewController
        .evaluateJavascript("Modal.showInModal('#nav-tools')"),
    Blacksmith()
  ];


        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue[700],
        selectedFontSize: 13,
        unselectedFontSize: 13,
        iconSize: 30,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "Feed",
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "Screen",
            icon: Icon(Icons.grid_view),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "Tools",
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "Account",
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
```